# How can my Perl script find its module in the same directory?

Tags: perl, module, directory

I recently wrote a new Perl script to kill processes based on either process name / user name and extended it using Classes so that I could reuse the process code in other programs. My current layout is -

```
/home/mutew/src/prod/pskill       <-- Perl script
/home/mutew/src/prod/Process.pm   <-- Package to handle process descriptions
```

I added ~/src/prod in my $PATH variable to access the script from anywhere. On running the script from any directory other than its resident directory leads to a "Can't locate Process.pm in @INC" (which is understandable given that other than the shared directories in /usr, @INC includes only the current directory - '.'). One workaround that I have been using is the use lib directive as so -

```
use lib '/home/mutew/src/prod';
```

but this is a major portability issue. Any solutions which will also allow me to export the script to other systems without and changes?

---

**EDIT**

1. I chose 'depesz' answer as the correct one because of its simplicity and core module usage.
2. brian d foy's answer though suggests other methods to accomplish the same (TMTOWTDI), his contribution in perlfaq8 renders this question absolutely redundant.

Comment: maybe it's just my installation, but if both files are in the same directory I simply "use FILENAME.pm". Then "my $newVar = PACKAGENAME->new();" for any object programming.

Comment: Wow this should be a lot easier in perl than this! Make the easy things easy etc.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The simplest approach I found it to use FindBin module. Like this:

```
use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::Bin;
```

Generally I prefer to have my scripts provided in such a way that programs are in whatever/bin, and libraries are in whatever/lib

In these situations I use a slightly more complicated approach:

```
use Cwd qw(abs_path);
use FindBin;
use lib abs_path("$FindBin::Bin/../lib");
```

The abs_path call is to make the @INC contain whatever/lib, and not whatever/bin/../lib - it's just a slight change, but makes reading error messages easier.

Comment: Don't forget that abs_path returns tainted result in taint mode. You must use `use lib (abs_path("$FindBin::Bin/../lib")=~m{^(/.*)})[0];` or just use `use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../lib";` beacuse there is no reason to canonize path.

Comment: This solution worked, but I went with the second solution (below) because FindBin had to be installed with CPAN, and I prefer the unencumbered aspect of File::Basename as a core module, when running across multiple machines.

Answer (score 81):

I am curious why the simplistic solution

```perl
use File::Basename;
use lib dirname (__FILE__);
use SomeModuleLocatedInTheSameDirectoryAsThisPerlScriptOrModule;
```

did not come up. The FindBin module seems to have some issues if the file is not the main executable perl script, but simply a non-executable Perl module. At least that's how I interpret the comment in the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html#KNOWN-ISSUES). Did not really test it.

To have any other path relative to the location of this Perl file, do something like

```perl
use File::Basename;
use lib dirname (__FILE__) . "/MyModules";
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot - I just had to use `use Cwd qw(abs_path); use lib dirname (abs_path(__FILE__));` to make the script callable through a symlink. Cheers!

Comment: This is the only answer worked for me by searching Google several minutes. And it is simple enough, clear enough and friendly to newbie.

Comment: This doesn't work well with namespaced modules, e.g. if under `somedir/Foo/Bar` you have `Foo::Bar::Baz` in `Baz.pm` and you want to import it from `Foo::Bar::Qux` in `Qux.pm` in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks, David, interesting point to consider. I would just add that if you use namespaces, wouldn't best practice be to then also import modules always with their full-qualified name? Otherwise you may end up importing the wrong module depending on the lib search path used.

Answer (score 15):

From [perlfaq8](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html), which answers ["How do I add a directory to my include path (@INC) at runtime?"](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_do_I_add_a_direc). There are several other answers for questions around this issue too.

---

How do I add a directory to my include path (@INC) at runtime?

Here are the suggested ways of modifying your include path, including environment variables, run-time switches, and in-code statements:

the PERLLIB environment variable

```
$ export PERLLIB=/path/to/my/dir
$ perl program.pl
```

the PERL5LIB environment variable

```
$ export PERL5LIB=/path/to/my/dir
$ perl program.pl
```

the perl -Idir command line flag

```
$ perl -I/path/to/my/dir program.pl
```

the use lib pragma:

```
use lib "$ENV{HOME}/myown_perllib";
```

The last is particularly useful because it knows about machine dependent architectures. The lib.pm pragmatic module was first included with the 5.002 release of Perl.

Comment: I read perlfaq8 later the same day and found the answer I needed in your contributed article. I wonder why you did include the second method (use Cwd) though since @INC already has an entry for the current directory - '.'

Answer (score 8):

Besides the already stated solutions:

1. use FindBin / lib
2. Perl Faq 8 [How do I add a directory to my include path (@INC) at runtime?](https://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-add-a-directory-to-my-include-path-INC-at-runtime)

'The simplest approach' (™) that I use while dev/testing a module prior
to deploying it (in /usr/local/lib/site_perl/ or elsewhere in @INC) is
to modify @INC before loading the module as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
# Modify @INC prior to module loading.
BEGIN { unshift @INC, '.'; }
use YourModuleInCWD;
```

([Add current working directory to @INC? - PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=375341))

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is simplest, has no dependencies, and is Perliest. I think it also has the bonus of being clearest to someone who recognizes what "." and @INC are.

Comment: @felwithe: It doesn't work, though - the question is about adding the directory that the _script_ is in, when that is _different_ from ".".

Answer (score 4):

You can make perl look in any directory by using the `-I` flag. Here, `-I` stands for `@INC` which is the array of paths in which perl looks for modules. Using `-I` adds the given path to the `@INC` array for this execution.

eg:

```
perl -I lib bin/script.pl
```

where lib contains the modules I want to use.

I know that this works for **perl 5**. I am not at sure about other versions.

Comment: This is the best answer.  For example:
#! /usr/bin/env perl -I ./
Simple solutions are always better than including still yet another obscure CPAN module.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Par::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR-Packer/lib/PAR/Packer.pm). It creates an executable with all of the script's dependencies included. It makes distribution easy. You also could also provide your users a version of your module that can be installed on their systems. See [Module::Starter](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Starter/lib/Module/Starter.pm) for an easy way to build all of the files required to make a standard CPAN-style distribution.

Answer (score 3):

The path can be included in perl script in first line, marked with `#!`

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -I.
use anymodule;
```

Comment: Easiest and cleanest answer by far.

Answer (score 0):

To convert relative links to absolute and add to @INC, I normally use ex::lib. Of course, this is useful only if you plan to keep the relative locations of the script and the module identical on all machines where you plan to run your script.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it simple. There is no need to import any libraries; just find out your current working directory:

```
use lib "$ENV{PWD}/relativ_path_own_perllib";
```

For similar problems, you can read out the environment variable which gives your information about where you are, your home directory, operating system stuff, and so on, with just one row of programming code in the shell-terminal, like:

```
perl -e 'map { print; print " : ". $ENV{$_}." \n\r"; } sort keys %ENV '
```

There is no need to bind some libraries; just use the `%ENV-Hash`.

Comment: `$ENV{PWD}` does not solve the problem - on the contrary. It returns the _user's working directory_, not the location of the script.

Answer (score -1):

[FindBin::libs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FindBin%3a%3alibs) will find all your libs placed at reasonable places relative to the path from where your script is running.